# Unable to get interference from milk using Time domain OCT (Michelson Morley interferometer) approach

Tags: interference, interferometry, coherence, camera

I was able to construct time domain Optical coherence tomography based on Michelson Morley interferometer using a LED. While testing the interferometer, I used glass slide, layers of scotch tape. I was able to get fringes from. but when I try to use milk drop as a sample I don’t see any fringes. To be noted I use, 4x objective lens of NA 0.1 and I use 12bit camera. Please let me know what may be the potential reason for not not getting fringes from the Milk.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly the milk particles are too small, the light randomly scatters throughout it, the returned scattered light then has random phase variations, and the fringes are washed out.

Ideally, you’ll have optical interfaces from which the light can reflect with a particular phase delay relative to the reference beam.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So if I use 10 um beads will I able to see fringes?

Comment: @safi Probably so! But if they are suspended in liquid, you could have trouble because they would be moving around during your measurement time, again washing out your fringes.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I wonder since the fringe will wash out will I see speckle